# Como rotar objeto en un esfera

Tags: c#, unity

estoy intentando hacer un juego donde el personaje esta sobre un planeta(esfera), puedo mover al personaje sin problemas pero no logro hacer que rote de forma correcta hacia donde se esta moviendo.

Que me esta faltando para que funcione correctamente?

Script de movimiento del personaje:

```
private Vector3 moveDirection;
Rigidbody rb;
float moveSpeed = 10;
float rotSpeed = 50;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    float moveH = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveV = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

    moveDirection = new Vector3(moveH, 0,moveV).normalized;


    if (moveH != 0f || moveV != 0f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection), rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + Time.deltaTime * moveDirection);
}
```

Script gravedad del persnaje:

```
GravityAttractor planet;
Rigidbody rigidbody;

void Awake()
{
    planet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Planet").GetComponent<GravityAttractor>();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    // Disable rigidbody gravity and rotation as this is simulated in GravityAttractor script
    rigidbody.useGravity = false;
    rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Allow this body to be influenced by planet's gravity
    planet.Attract(rigidbody);
}
```

Scrip gravedad del planeta:

```
public float gravity = -9.8f;


public void Attract(Rigidbody body)
{
    Vector3 gravityUp = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Vector3 localUp = body.transform.up;

    // Apply downwards gravity to body
    body.AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);
    // Allign bodies up axis with the centre of planet
    body.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(localUp, gravityUp) * body.rotation;
}
```